# Serial voteup someone you learn from

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

**Why is it wrong to serial voteup someone you like his answers?**

Sometimes I just came to stackoverflow to read certain people answers(there are 4 guys currently) I have their profile bookmarked in my browser and in my free time at office I go to their profile and read their answers and learn a lot from them, but because I'm afraid to be a serial voter, I dont voteup them.

I think there is nothing wrong with that, if there is, please let me know.

Comment: why the vote down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should focus on the **post**, not on a user.

It is quite strange, however, that you are keep reading posts from some certain users (if you want some knowledge on some theme, search for this *theme* and not search a user, good at this theme). Maybe you have good purposes, but system **can't** identify if you are up voting a person to give him rep, or simply read all his answers for beginning to end and every answer is good.

The thing you are doing won't bring any rep to this user, all the serial votes will be reversed on the next day, but will bring bad outcome both to you and this user: he may be suspected having a sock puppet account and you can be suspended for voting serially.

If you like some answer, you can add a bounty on the post and award it to that answer, but remember that serially offering bounties can also be a bit strange behavior, you can also be suspected to be a sock puppet of this user.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm not willing to upvote every answer, and also I'm reading about those things, but some of their answers are tricky, and although I see them in books or websites but the way they highlight are interesting for me.

Comment: If user X serially upvotes user Y, I don't think that Y would be suspended for "having a sock puppet" without a proper investigation looking at IP addresses. If both are known users, and known to be different people, I think the consequences would only hit X, who might get a warning about serial voting.